# Client dial time imported wrong in Cisco's Contact Center outbound campaign

Tags: cisco

Using Cisco's Unified Contact Center Express 9.0.2-11001-24 I'm attempting to create new outbound campaign with a set of clients.

Importing the clients via the REST API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<campaignContacts>
     <campaign name="test">
          <refURL>https://host:8443/adminapi/campaign/23</refURL>
     </campaign>
     <csvdata>
          Account Number, First Name, Last Name, Phone1, Phone2, Phone3, Dial Time
          1, John, Doe, 1234, 5678, 9012, 14:05
          2, Joe, Smith, 2222, 3333, 4444, 14:24
     </csvdata>
</campaignContacts>
```

is successful but querying the contacts with

```
https://host:8443/adminapi/campaign/23/contacts
```

gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<campaignContacts>
     <campaign name="test">
          <refURL>https://host:8443/adminapi/campaign/23</refURL>
     </campaign>
     <csvdata>
account number, first name, last name, phone1, phone2, phone3, dial time    
 1, John, Doe, 1234, 5678, 9012, 10:5
 2, Joe, Smith, 2222, 3333, 4444, 10:24
     </csvdata>
</campaignContacts>
```

The dial time is not imported correctly and the contact is called directly.

I've tried using HHmm instead of HH:mm but that doesn't work either.

The documentation  **[HERE](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cust_contact/contact_center/crs/express_9_0/configuration/guide/UCCX_BK_U767AC77_00_uccx-admin-guide_chapter_01100.html#UCCX_TK_I49DFB90_00__steps_4BBA35D93E294428A4416A84E2DEA333)**  clearly says that:

> DialTime field is used to specify the time to dial a number for individual contacts on the current date. The format to be used for this field is HH:MM. For example, to specify the dialing time as 08:25 am, the dial time field value should be 08:25 and for 03:45 pm, the dial time field value should be 15:45.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some testing it turned out that `DialTime` is actually working correctly. The contacts weren't called on time because of the `Callback Time Limit` setting of the campaign.

Querying the contacts with `https://host:8443/adminapi/campaign/{id}/contacts` is broken and shows wrong `DialTime` values